# How to make content auto scroll from top to bottom and back up?

Tags: html

If I have div element and inside that element I have some content (text), and if that content takes more space then it's the height of div element, how can I make the content automatically non-stop scroll from to bottom and back up?

Comment: Is it something like this you're looking for? https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/ZEGrBJa

Comment: @BjørnNyborg No. When I open the page, the text should start scrolling to the bottom, and when It comes to the end, it start to scroll to the top again.

Comment: i need a better explanation on what you want to achieve. Have you seen this effect somewhere else, that you can show? Or maybe make a drawing of how it should look/work.
As far as i can see, my codepen does exactly what you ask for.